# How to filter the last items of every week?

Tags: json, jq, iso8601, dayofweek, weekend

I have json data which contains a datetime field in ISO 8601 format. I want to filter out all items which happened during the weekend. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using UTC(!) datetimes and `jq` is linked against a `libc` which supports `strftime()`, then you can use something like this:

*file.json*:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "date": "2018-02-11T12:00:00Z"
}
{
  "name": "bar",
  "date": "2018-02-12T12:00:00Z"
}
```

`jq` command:

```
jq '.[]|select(.date|fromdateiso8601|strftime("%w") as $d|$d=="7" or $d=="0")' file.json
```

`7` stands for Saturday, `0` for Sunday.

Output:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "date": "2018-02-11T12:00:00Z"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shamelessly advertising.

You could use the jf version, which support all the python libraries. For Saturday and Sunday:

```
pip install jf
jf 'filter(date(x.date).weekday() > 4)' file.json
```